# Add PATH to .bashrc

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to install [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#linux-install) on my Linux machine.
Right or wrong, at the end of the instructions they say to

> add this line to the file .bashrc in your home directory: export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

I do not know much of how the PATH in bash works.
But, I have another PATH in my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/rsi/idl/bin:$PATH"
```

How am I supposed to add the new path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should be it (all paths wanted in ${PATH} separated by colons) :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/rsi/idl/bin:/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to just add the line, so that you have two lines changing the path:

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/share/rsi/idl/bin:$PATH"
```

The other option is to just change the existing line to this:

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/share/rsi/idl/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple path export,
In single line,

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/first/path:/second/path:/third/path
```

Multiple paths as

```
export PATH="A"
export PATH="B:$PATH"
export PATH="C:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the only one who suggests `{PATH}`. Why is that different?

Comment: Read as `${path}` - it will append the previously defined or other exported paths as well!